# Can we Access Synchronized method and an unsynchronized method of same instance from multiple threads at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, java-threads

It might seem to be a very naive question but I cannot find any concrete answer anywhere. I tried it even practically but since we cannot predict the behaviour of threads resource allocation in Java, it's really difficult to determine.
I just want to know if I can access a synchronized method and and unsynchronized method of a class at the same time from two different threads of same instance of that class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see any problems. Try out this:

```
public class Main {

    public static final SyncNotsynced sn = new SyncNotsynced();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(sn::synced);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(sn::notsynced);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public static class SyncNotsynced {

        public synchronized void synced(){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enter synced");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +  " exit synced");
        }

        public void notsynced(){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enter notsynced");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +  " exit notsynced");
        }
    }
}
```

or take look at the [***live example***](https://ideone.com/yMJiv3) :). As you can see enterings of `Thread 1` and `Thread 2` are both happened before exiting:

```
Thread-0 enter synced
Thread-1 enter notsynced
Thread-0 exit synced
Thread-1 exit notsynced
```

For a formal explanation you can read [JLS 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html), but in short only one thread can enter a synchronized block on the same object monitor.

Btw, I used `Thread.sleep` [because](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) (emphasize mine):

> Thread.sleep causes the currently executing thread to sleep
>   (temporarily cease execution) for the specified duration, subject to
>   the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. ***The thread***
>   ***does not lose ownership of any monitors***, and resumption of execution
>   will depend on scheduling and the availability of processors on which
>   to execute the thread.

Comment: Minor: OP does ask about instance methods. I know the static doesn't make a difference, you do too... But for the sake of OP's understanding, could you make your example demonstrate it?